# Can we crawl/scrape information from a FB page? If yes, how to get the correct css selectors?

Tags: ruby, web-crawler

I have been trying to crawl a fb page. I haven't been successful in retrieving anything useful.I want the links of the posts made on the page. Below is the code I have been using:

```
 require 'rubygems'
 require 'nokogiri'
 require 'open-uri'
 require 'logger'  
 require 'curb'

 $LOG = Logger.new('log_file.log', 'monthly') 

 http = Curl.get("https://www.facebook.com/thegluebomb") do |http|
  http.headers['User-Agent'] = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36"
 end

 html = Nokogiri::HTML(http.body_str)

 rows = html.css(".clearfix").each do |node|
          puts node.inner_html, "\n\n"
        end 
 $LOG.debug("rows: #{rows}")
```

I think my Css selector is wrong, but the fb page is so complicated I m not able to get the right css selectors. Can somebody please guide me how to do it?

Comment: I think, you should use somethin like Watir or Mechanize, if you want to scrap facebook

Comment: @AlexGolubenko The problem is of choosing the right css selector which I am not able to. I have tried the c ss selector tools as well but they didn't work well.

Comment: Write more specifically what content you need, please

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do it (I had also) but you need a more advanced crawler and a deep knolowdge about HTTP protocol and JS, using Dev Browser Tools like the one of Chrome is vital because you have to figure out which asyncronous requests is the browser doing, wich are the parameters, headers, cookies, etc.